# Identifying a couple of varistors

Tags: identification, varistor

I am looking for a replacement for these varistors, but I know nothing about the numbers on them. Please help me make sense of the numbers here; what do they mean, and what type/value are these?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can look up both in [this datasheet](https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/protection/voltage/lead-disk-varistor/data_sheet/70/db/var/siov_leaded_advanced.pdf). Many component suppliers like Mouser have these, just search for S14K300 and S20K550 on their website.

Comment: As @ocrdu said. The logo is EPCOS (now TDK); I believe the SIOV series (or a relative thereof) even dates back to Siemens (a combined hyphen-S logo), with the other markings still very similar to these. Incidentally, the pictured parts don't appear failed; I would not replace them if they pass electrical tests. (Perhaps these photos are from working equipment; that would explain that.)

Comment: Yes I know they are good. I have identical units that the parts are so blown out that there is nothing to read left on them. They pair with a capacitor that I was able to find no problem I just was not sure on the variations of MOV that I have found, especially for the S14 K300.

Comment: Do the 15 52 on the bottom signify anything important?